# Validating a CCN in Java?

Tags: java, validation, credit-card, equation

I am attempting to write a credit card validator. I can not, how ever, figure out for the life of me why the perfectly valid credit cards I'm inputting are coming up invalid.

I'm using the Luhn equation for validation.

The Luhn method is as follows:

## The Luhn Formula:

- Drop the last digit from the number. The last digit is what we want
  to check against
- Reverse the numbers.
- Multiply the digits in odd positions (1, 3, 5, etc.) by 2 and subtract 9 to all any result higher than 9.
- Add all the numbers together The check digit (the last    number of
  the card) is the amount that you would need to add to get a
  multiple of 10 (Modulo 10)

Credit cards examples are coming from [this website, where I also got the equation from.](http://www.freeformatter.com/credit-card-number-generator-validator.html)

My code is [here, on Gist.](https://gist.github.com/DigiDuncan/f4959e9cee5671742285)

Thanks!

(Also, this is my first time with Javadoc! Let me knwo how I did!)

## EDIT: The Luhn method I'm using that apparently doesn't work:

```
/**
 * Runs the Luhn Equation on a user inputed CCN, which in turn
 * determines if it is a valid card number.
 * @param c A user inputed CCN.
 * @param cn The check number for the card.
 * @return If the card is valid based on the Luhn Equation.
 */
public boolean luhn (String c, char cn)
{
    String card = c;

    //Drop the last digit.
    card = card.substring(0, ( card.length() - 1 ) );

    //Reverse the digits.
    String cardrev = new StringBuilder(card).reverse().toString();

    //Store it in an int array.
    char[] cardArray = cardrev.toCharArray();
    int[] cardWorking = new int[cardArray.length];
    int addedNumbers = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++)
    {
        cardWorking[i] = Character.getNumericValue( cardArray[i] );
    }

    //Double odd digits (which are really even in our case, since index starts at 0).

    for (int j = 0; j < cardWorking.length; j++)
    {
        if ( j % 2) == 0)
        {
            cardWorking[j] = cardWorking[j] * 2;
        }
    }

    //Subtract 9 from digits larger than 9.

    for (int k = 0; k < cardWorking.length; k++)
    {
        if (cardWorking[k] > 9)
        {
            cardWorking[k] = cardWorking[k] - 9;
        }
    }

    //Add all the numbers together.
    for (int l = 0; l < cardWorking.length; l++)
    {
        addedNumbers += cardWorking[l];
    }

    //Finally, check if the number we got from adding all the other numbers
    //when divided by ten has a remainder equal to the check number.
    if (addedNumbers % 10 == cn)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

## EDIT 2:

I think the problem is here, but I'm not sure why. `addedNumbers` is 50, and `cn` is 0, but it's still returning false.

```
if (addedNumbers % 10 == cn)
{
    //Debug
    System.out.println(addedNumbers + " % 10 = " + cn);

    return true;
}
else
{           
    //Debug
    System.out.println(addedNumbers + " % 10 =/= " + cn);

    return false;
}
```

My output in console:

```
>4024007142327070
707232417004204
[7, 0, 7, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 7, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 4]
[14, 0, 14, 2, 6, 2, 8, 1, 14, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 8]
[5, 0, 5, 2, 6, 2, 8, 1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 8]
50
50 % 10 =/= 0

You inputted card: 4024007142327070
Your card is not valid because it doesn't check against the Luhn Equation.
```

> **50 % 10 =/= 0**

Well that's not right. What's going on here?

### Quick Edit.

I was so mad, I checked.

[image: 50 modulo 10 is in fact, 0.]

50 modulo 10 is in fact, 0.

Comment: Links die. Please post a minimal example here which demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: @Takendarkk Well, the link isn't dead on my end, but I'll edit the method into the post.

Comment: I know it's not dead now. Let me rephrase. Links can, and probably will, die in the future so instead of relying on them just post your content here.

Comment: @Takendarkk I understand your concern. Posted the method.

Comment: `Multiply the digits in *odd positions*  (1, 3, 5, etc.) by 2` while you do: `Multiple odd digits by 2`.

Comment: @fukanchik Changed line 60 in CCNEquations to `if ( (j % 2) == 0)` with no luck. Still will not validate. Changed in post as well, as it still doesn't work.

Comment: @fukanchik Added more info to the post. See if you can help?

Comment: @Takendarkk Added more info to the post. See if you can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you doing it wrong here :

```
//Finally, check if the number we got from adding all the other numbers
    //when divided by ten has a remainder equal to the check number.
    if (addedNumbers % 10 == cn)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

`addedNumbers` is an `int`. `cn` is `char`.

Try this :
`System.out.println(1 == '1');`

This will always be false.

EDIT :

It does an ascii value comparison and hence never throws an error.

For example, this would result in `TRUE` :
System.out.println(49 == '1');

Comment: For some reason I thought Java would auto cast char to int. Thanks so much!

Comment: Edited with your auto cast doubt.

Comment: I fixed it by adding `String checkString = "" + cn; int check = Integer.valueOf(checkString);` and then later changing the check to `if (addedNumbers % 10 == check)`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use org.apache.commons.validator.CreditCardValidator from apache commons-validator.

Comment: That;s no fun! The point of the program is to do it manually!